# head and tail command output together on file

Tags: command-line, tail

Suppose I am having file named `file1.txt` with the content as `1,2,3.. upto 100 linewise.`

```
$> head -n 5 file1.txt //will display first 5 lines i.e. 1,2,3,4,5
$> tail -n 5 file1.txt // will display last 5 lines i.e. 96,97,98,99,100
```

I want to display the content as first 5 lines and last 5 lines together in 1 command,

```
$> head tail -n 5 file1.txt // Something like this 1,2,3,4,5   96,97,98,99,100 (both together)
```

how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Suppose you take the [tour] read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. At least show some effort.

Comment: `{ head -n 5 file1.txt ; tail -n 5 file1.txt ;  }`

Comment: @24601, thank you for letting me know.. I have already put my efforts of research, but could not find the similar one. I wanted it one command, may be using piping or redirect or anything else. anyways thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use curly braces in bash to combine more than one command and having also their *stdout* and *stderr* combined:

```
{ head -n 5 file1.txt ; tail -n 5 file1.txt ; }
```

Notice that there is space character between the braces and the commands enclosed within them. That is because `{` and `}` are reserved words here (commands built into the shell). They mean *group the outputs of all these commands together*.

Also notice that the list of commands has to end with a semicolon (`;`).

If you want to create an "alias" for such a command combination, you can create a *function* (a simple *Bash alias* will not work) in your `.bash_aliases` file like this:

```
function headtail
{
  head "$@" ; tail "$@"
}
```

And you can call this function like this, for example:

```
headtail -n6 file1.txt | wc -l
```

In the above example, if `file1.txt` is has at least 6 lines, you will get an output of `12` from the `wc` command.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `head -n2 file.txt ; tail -n2 file.txt` also work, or is there something specific to using the curly braces?

Comment: To combine the output.

Comment: It is also combined without the curly braces.

Comment: Its near to the required answer, either by using `;` (semicolon between the commands)  or by using `bash_aliases` , can be accepted as answer. thank you for your help..

Answer (score 3):

Processing in a sub-shell:

```
(head -n 5; tail -n 5) < file1.txt
```